# Select2 Css is not loading via yarn or assets precompile

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jquery-select2, yarnpkg, webpacker, ruby-on-rails-6

I am running into a strange issue where everything is working as expected except select2. I am having Rails 6.0.0 app and installed select2 via `yarn add select2`.

Then i added it to application.js file. File looks like below.

```
    #app/javascripts/packs/application.js

    require("@rails/ujs").start()
    require("turbolinks").start()
    require("@rails/activestorage").start()
    require("channels")
    require('datatables.net')
    require('datatables.net-dt')
    require('datatables.net-bs4')
    require('select2')

    import  "bootstrap"
    import 'popper.js/dist/popper.js';
    import $ from 'jquery';
    global.$ = jQuery;
    import  "chart.js"
    import 'select2'; // globally assign select2 fn to $ element
    import 'select2/dist/css/select2.css';  // optional if you have css loader

    document.addEventListener("turbolinks:load", () => {
        setTimeout(function() {
          $('.success, .alert').fadeOut();
        }, 10000); 
    })
```

Right now it looks like this 
[select2 dropdown box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3YPDD.png)

When I go to Source tab in chrome developer tools, it shows only `select2/dist/js` folder under node_modules. I have tried `precompiling` and `clobbering` the assets but not working. The whole this is running fine in my local, only causing issue in production server.

Edit:

My production.rb

https://gist.github.com/rajanhcah/3ee13925b0ae305a6fe2c64013ab6534

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you're including CSS in `app/javascripts/packs/application.js`, make sure that `app/views/layouts/application.html.erb` is also using the `stylesheet_pack_tag` (see the ["Usage" section](https://github.com/rails/webpacker#usage) in the webpacker doc).

Otherwise, if you have `stylesheet_link_tag`, you can use the classical `app/assets/stylesheets/application.css`.

```
# app/assets/stylesheets/application.scss
@import 'select2/dist/css/select2';
```

Comment: HI, I understand the concern. I had the thought why even i need to write this line `import 'select2/dist/css/select2.css'` . It should be auto included with `require('select2')` . Also, if what you are saying is right, how it is working in local?

Comment: Also i tried putting `@import "select2";` in application.scss. it says not found

Comment: If you added it via yarn, you need to give the full path: `@import 'select2/dist/css/select2';`

Comment: It worked. Thanks.  But how do you know about this? Why we need to put absolute path? Doesn't yarn looks in node_modules by default?

Comment: Good! I edited my answer with the comment. The reason you need to provide the full path is because most of the times, external librairies have multiple paths with .css and js files (sometimes just `/dist/file.js` and `/dist/file.js`, sometimes `dist/css/file.css` and `src/css/file.css`)...the asset pipeline can't know which one you want.

Comment: This worked for me too. To be really specific, I went into `app/views/layouts/application.html.erb` and added the line `<%= stylesheet_pack_tag 'application' %>` (and also kept the `stylesheet_link_tag` line). Thank you for your answer and help

Comment: This worked for me too, thanks a lot, save my weekend :)