# How to make Select2 work with rails 6 app in production?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, webpack, jquery-select2, ruby-on-rails-6

I have a Rails 6 app. I am using the select2 plugin. It works in development, but it does not work in production (Heroku).

I ran

```
yarn add select2
```

Here is application.js

```
require("@rails/ujs").start()
require("@rails/activestorage").start()
require("channels")
require("jquery")
require("chartkick")
require("chart.js")
require("custom/scripts")
require("custom/programs")
```

Here is package.json

```
{
  "name": "case_reporter",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@primer/css": "^14.2.0",
    "@rails/actioncable": "^6.0.0",
    "@rails/activestorage": "^6.0.0",
    "@rails/ujs": "^6.0.0",
    "@rails/webpacker": "4.2.2",
    "chart.js": "^2.9.3",
    "chartkick": "^3.2.0",
    "jquery": "^3.4.1",
    "select2": "^4.0.13",
    "turbolinks": "^5.2.0"
  },
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "devDependencies": {
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.10.3"
  }
}
```

Here is my select js in custom/programs.js

```
import $ from 'jquery'
import 'select2'
import 'select2/dist/css/select2.css'

window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  $('.js-source-programs').select2()
})
```

here is environment.js

```
const { environment } = require('@rails/webpacker')

const webpack = require('webpack')

environment.plugins.prepend('Provide',
  new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
    $: 'jquery/src/jquery',
    jQuery: 'jquery/src/jquery'
  })
)

module.exports = environment
```

In my html I have:

```
= f.collection_select :program_type_id, ProgramType.all, :id, :name, { class: 'form-select js-source-programs' }
```

It is working in development without any problems.

In production on Heroku, it is not working. AND there are no errors in the console.

What could cause this to not work in production?

Here is the head

```
  %head
    %meta{:content => "text/html; charset=UTF-8", "http-equiv" => "Content-Type"}/
    %meta{:content => "width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no", :name => "viewport"}/
    %title CS-DM
    = csrf_meta_tags
    = csp_meta_tag
    = stylesheet_link_tag 'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload'
    = javascript_pack_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload'

    %script{:src => "https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v1.5.0/mapbox-gl.js"}
    %link{:href => "https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v1.5.0/mapbox-gl.css", :rel => "stylesheet"}/
```

Comment: I remember the order of scripts in the head element could be a cause. Can you add those?

Comment: Given there are no errors in the console I am going to ask the dumb question, you have enough data to add items to the select menu, correct?  There are program types in the DB?

Comment: @RockwellRice yes, I have data. The select shows up just not with the select2 stuff.

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue - this answer resolved it for me: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58007621/4741698

The issue is including CSS in application.js without adding `<%= stylesheet_pack_tag 'application.js', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>`. So either add the `stylesheet_pack_tag`, or move the CSS to a file that is already included with a stylesheet_pack_tag.